# How to write my own parser in Apache Nutch 1.6 binary distribution to extract html pages?

Tags: html-parsing, nutch

I am trying to write my own custom parser in Apache Nutch 1.6 binary distribution, but I can't find any help anywhere.

Comment: the question is to broad for people to help you. Please state the problem you are having and incorporate your code into the post. Then people will be able to help you.

Comment: [Apache Nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/) is an open source project and it already includes parsers for many document formats. Parser implementations are pluggable and the to learn from the source code how a parser is implemented. Working with the binary packages alone is difficult, why not use the existing sources which include a build configuration etc. The recent version of Nutch is 1.16 - working with an older version could be challenging: 1.6 has been released in 2012 and is based on Java 6.

Comment: I am trying to crawl a website but with the default configuration, the whole website is coming into one field 'content' while indexing in Solr, so I want to write my own parser to parse only those fields which I want as we do in beautiful soup. I am using binary distribution so I also want to know whether I can write my own parser in binary distribution or not?